# All rows are black in the Watch Window when debugging in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I just installed VS2012, and I noticed that the variables in the Watch Window have black background, and are thus unreadable (I assume the text is also black, so black on black = unreadable).

What causes this problem, and how can I fix it?

So far I've found some links - [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760291/vs2012-with-dark-theme-prints-code-with-black-background), [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763007/black-lines-in-watch-window) and [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/764956/rows-in-watch-list-are-black) link, all from connect.microsoft.com. I'll see if I can find any solutions there.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer from https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760291/vs2012-with-dark-theme-prints-code-with-black-background.

From user Murali:

> Can you try resetting the printer category in Fonts and Colors ? To do
>   this, you can go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and
>   Colors -> Choose the Printer Category (which is below the Text Editor
>   category) and then click on Use Defaults.
>
> Do let us know if that solves the problem.
>
> Thanks, Murali Murali Krishna Hosabettu Kamalesha | Program Manager |
>   Visual Studio Professional - Editor team

I did this, and indeed it fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer solves the problem for me: 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763007/black-lines-in-watch-window

Go to Tools - Options - Environment - Fonts and Colors. Select Merge - Block selection box in the list of Display items and change Item background to White.

I'm using a customized theme, the other solution would cancel the theme I'm using.